# Grant read permission for folder in Raspberry Pi 3 via Power Shell

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I connected to Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows IoT installed with Power Shell.
I have some folder: `COMDriver` which is invisible through Windows Device Portal -> File Explorer.
`ls` gives follow result:

```
[192.168.1.17]: PS C:\Data\USERS\administrator> ls


    Directory: C:\Data\USERS\administrator


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-r---        1/24/2019   5:24 PM                3D Objects
d-----        2/11/2019   5:34 PM                COMDriver
d-r---        1/24/2019   5:24 PM                Documents
d-r---        1/24/2019   5:24 PM                Downloads
d-----        1/24/2019   5:24 PM                Favorites
d-r---        1/24/2019   5:24 PM                Music
d-r---        1/24/2019   5:24 PM                Pictures
d-r---        1/24/2019   5:24 PM                Videos
```

I guess that I need to grant read permissions for a file, how ever Set-Acl doesn't have such an option.
What shell I do?

Comment: I don't think permissions might actually be the problem. But if you want to take a look at it, ofc you can do this with `Set-Acl`! You just have to create the responding ACL-Objekt first (https://ss64.com/ps/set-acl.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even set the ACL-Object via Set-Acl command, the folder is also invisible through File Explorer in Device Portal. This is by design.The root folders that Device Portal shows are hardcoded. I think there were security concerns about enabling a full File Explorer on certain SKUs.  I want to know why did you want to view the custom folder though Device Portal. In fact, you can view the folders via file manager on your PC through following steps.

1. Open file manager in your PC
2. Open any drive and type the following line in path-
   \{your pi address}\c$\Data\Users\administrator
3. Now press enter,you can access the pi with pc

In addition, Universal Windows Apps (apps) can access certain file system locations by default. Please see this [topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f61a4180-61d5-4a01-84b6-6e9554b1b38e/file-access-on-windows-iot-core?forum=WindowsIoT) in MSDN forum and [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). I think the File Explorer in device portal follows this principle.